# netbeans: how to set value to control which is retrieved from database?

Tags: java, netbeans, jdatechooser

I want to fetch records from database & want to set on form. In this form I am using `JDateChooser` from `JCalendar`. I have written the following code for this:

```
public void showdata()

    int a=leaveView.getSelectedRow();
    int b=(Integer)leaveView.getValueAt(a, 0);
    String c=(String)leaveView.getValueAt(a, 1);
    String d=(String)leaveView.getValueAt(a, 2);
    String e=(String)leaveView.getValueAt(a, 3);
    String f=(String)leaveView.getValueAt(a, 4);
    String  g=(String)leaveView.getValueAt(a, 5);
    String h=(String)leaveView.getValueAt(a, 6);
    int i=(Integer)leaveView.getValueAt(a, 7);  
    String j = (String)leaveView.getValueAt(a, 8);
    String k = (String)leaveView.getValueAt(a, 9);


    AL.empid.setSelectedItem(b);
    AL.empname.setText(c);
    AL.empname.setEditable(true);
    AL.department.setText(d);
    AL.department.setEditable(true);
    AL.leavetype.setSelectedItem(e);
    AL.other.setText(f);
    AL.other.setEditable(true);
    AL.jDateChooser1.setDate(g);
    AL.jDateChooser2.setDate(h);

    AL.noofdays.setText(""+i);
    AL.noofdays.setEditable(true);
    AL.singleday.setSelected(true);
    AL.multipleday.setSelected(true);
}
```

but it's setting today's date to `JDateChooser` by default... it's not displaying the date which is retrieved from database... The above code is throwing an error at lines  `AL.jDateChooser1.setDate(g)` and `AL.jDateChooser2.setDate(h)` for g & h...What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using this [JCalendar API](http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/)

From the [javadocs](http://www.toedter.com/en/jcalendar/api/index.html) setDate accepts a date object and not a string. First convert(parse) the dateString(g & h) to Date objects then set the date.

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); //adjust this according to your requirement
Date gDate,hDate;
        try {
            gDate = df.parse(g);
            hDate = df.parse(h);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

AL.jDateChooser1.setDate(gDate);
AL.jDateChooser2.setDate(hDate);
```

for some example date formats,visit http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html